# C++11/ Auto - How i should make this?

Tags: c++, c++11

Hy all of you.

Soo i decided to mygrate my code to c++11.
To simplify my code i want to use `auto` for `iterators`

This is my code .

```
bool Blend_Item_init()
{
    BLEND_ITEM_INFO *blend_item_info = NULL;
    T_BLEND_ITEM_INFO::iterator iter;
    char file_name[256];
    snprintf (file_name, sizeof(file_name), "%s/blend.txt", LocaleService_GetBasePath().c_str());

    sys_log(0, "Blend_Item_init %s ", file_name);

    DO_ALL_BLEND_INFO(iter)
    {
        blend_item_info = *iter;
        M2_DELETE(blend_item_info);
    }
    s_blend_info.clear();

    if (false==Blend_Item_load(file_name))
    {
        sys_err("<Blend_Item_init> fail");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

How i should make this code more short in c++11 with `auto` ?
And also i can use a smart pointer in this function ?

Edit: `DO_ALL_BLEND_INFO(iter)` is defined as

```
#define DO_ALL_BLEND_INFO(iter) for (iter=s_blend_info.begin();iter!=s_blend_info.end(); ++iter) –
```

Comment: what is `DO_ALL_BLEND_INFO(iter)` ?

Comment: #define DO_ALL_BLEND_INFO(iter) for (iter=s_blend_info.begin();iter!=s_blend_info.end(); ++iter)

Comment: I don't really get the obsession, by some people, to make their code "as short as possible". Go for readability, not for length.

Comment: You have C++11. That macro should be replaced with a range-based for loop here. Or make the container store something that cleans itself up and you won't need a deletion loop.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius It's not only to make my code short. Just to improve with c++11 :D

Comment: You actually do not have to do anything to "migrate" working c++ code to make it work with c++11

Comment: I also want to rewrite this macro as c++ code. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `auto` and range based for, you can replace the for loop that was hidden by the macro with the following and get rid of the macros entirely:

```
for(auto blend_item_info : s_blend_info)
    M2_DELETE(blend_item_info);
```

It's both shorter and easier to read.